# Storing JSON image Data in an array and displaying it in tableViewCell using Swift

Tags: json, swift, xcode, swift2

I am trying to store the Images from a JSON in an array and displaying it in a TableViewCell using a TableViewController. But the array not only stores the image but also the quality/size of the Image i.e. {53,53}. I don't know how to get the Image from it.
I Have a UIImage in my Table View Controller name 'gameImage'.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

  var NumberOfRows = 5
  var arrayOfImages = [UIImage]()
  let ImageData=NSData()
  override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
       let url = NSURL(string:"https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topgrossingipadapplications/limit=25/json")

    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
    let task  = session.dataTaskWithRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url!)) {(data,response,error) -> Void in


            let swiftyJSON  = JSON(data: data!)

        for i in 1...6{
            var theEntryArray = swiftyJSON["feed"]["entry"][i-1]["im:image"].arrayValue
            let imageArray = theEntryArray[0]["label"].string!
            let ImageUrl = NSURL(string: imageArray)

            let ImageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: ImageUrl!)

            self.arrayOfImages.append(UIImage(data:ImageData!)!)



        }

    }

    task.resume()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.




}
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) ->Int {
    return 20
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell


    let pho=arrayOfImages[indexPath.row]
    cell.gameImage.image = pho

    return cell
}


}
```

The Output of the arrayOfImages looks like:

```
 [<UIImage: 0x7ff893f8c990>, {53, 53}, <UIImage: 0x7ff893f62830>, {53, 53}, <UIImage: 0x7ff893c599c0>, {53, 53}, <UIImage: 0x7ff893f95740>, {53, 53}, <UIImage: 0x7ff893c5c900>, {53, 53}, <UIImage: 0x7ff893e3fee0>, {53, 53}]
```

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Try to add self: let pho = self.arrayOfImage...  Then make an if let condition first, it is safe: if let pho = self.arrayOfImages ... { cell. .. = pho }

Answer (score 1):

It is crashing because your image array may empty or not contain 20 objects, In `numberOfRowsInSection` you are returning 20, to solve this issue with `numberOfRowsInSection` you need to return the count of your `imageArray` like this.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) ->Int {
   return arrayOfImages.count
}
```

**Note:** It is just suggestion instead of downloading image using `NSData` try to use third party lib like SDWebImage and other that will give you more benefits.

Comment: An imageArray is not empty.

Comment: @pedrouan But it is contain 20 objects as you returning 20 in `numberOfRowsInSection`? check that

Comment: That's true. But it is not empty. Anyway, your answer doesn't solve theirs whole problem. Try to edit your answer with solution that he still needs.

Comment: @pedrouan My answer is correct OP app is crashing because there is no 20 objects inside array and when in cellForRowAtIndexPath it will try to access object it is crashing check properly.

Comment: "_I don't know how to get the Image from it._" he says first

Comment: but I cannot display anything in the cells. The function" override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell" is not working. I tried printing"hello" in it, but its not printing

Comment: @ChandramauliKaushik You need to reload tableView after you get all the image.`self.tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: @serg_zhd Without knowing doesn't put comment have you ever try to print object of `UIImage` it will always display this type of detail that op is saying.

Comment: @ChandramauliKaushik Have you reload the tableView as I have suggested?

Comment: Yes.  
    func do_table_refresh()
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            return
        })
    }
And i called it in viewdidload().

Comment: but still The function" override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell" is not called

Comment: @NiravD , Yes. func do_table_refresh() { dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { self.tableView.reloadData() return }) } And i called it in viewdidload().   
but still The function" override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell" is not called. :(

Comment: @ChandramauliKaushik `NSData(contentsOfURL:` is async method, your image will take time to download that is the reason i have suggest you to use SDWebImage library, check that lib it will help you and take less time to download image if it is already in its cache.